# floating point exception in isql with mariadb

Tags: mariadb, debian, unixodbc

I have this problem in my Debian server :

```
$ isql -v asterisk-connector
[1]    13397 floating point exception  isql -v asterisk-connector
```

I already checked logs `/` google and got nothing

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.3 (jessie)
Release:    8.3
Codename:   jessie

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

unixODBC 2.3.1
```

This configuration works on other non Debian servers but now I have this problem only on Debian even calling unixODBC 3

```
$ isql -3 -v asterisk-connector
[1]    13464 floating point exception  isql -3 -v asterisk-connector
```

If I missed any information require for debugging let me know

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/446483/how-to-investigate-mariadb-unixodbc-issue-further

Comment: Same error when connecting asterisk database (Official MySQL 5.7.x running on Fedora 24) from debian-unstable (unixODBC 2.3.1, libmyodbc 5.1.10).

Comment: Please add setup information used in your /etc/odbc.ini and /etc/odbcinst.ini.